# page not found 404 django

Tags: python, django, url, http-status-code-404

> > Page not found (404) Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/ Using the URLconf defined in
> >     Hello.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ admin/ [name='home'] service [name='service'] contact
>   [name='contact'] about [name='about'] The current path, about/, didn't
>   match any of these.[![enter image description here][1]][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZMW9.png

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this warning because you haven't defined a pattern that will direct the user to that page. So if you are doing this in a new application or the root part? Inform us about that. Either way you should go to "urls" and add the path to that folder. You can use the default "admin/" to teach you. For examle delete admin and write "abc/" and when you write"/abc" to your browser it'll show up.

Comment: i used every steps same for 'contact' and and 'sevice' and they working fine but only prolem with 'about'